# Synchronize Azure database with local database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to synchronize an existing azure database with a local database? . What we need is to have the local database data updated with data in the cloud database. Running the synchronization once a day would work fine for us. If is it possible, what solutions exists ( specially free solutions)

Thanks

Comment: what's your local database? and by Azure database, do you mean Azure SQL Database or database in SQL Server VM in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Azure SQL Data Sync](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/)?  It allows you to synchronise parts of a database from on premise to the cloud or vice versa.

Your Windows Azure SQL Database is the **hub** database, whilst your on premise database is the **reference** database.

You can register an on premise client database using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823138.aspx), then set up a Sync Group to synchronise all changes between the two databases.  This can either be bi-directional, from hub (hub changes sync to reference db only) or to hub (reference db changes sync to hub only).